# How can I estimate the payment date?

Tags: statistics, prediction, data-analysis

I have a list of sellers and want to pay them after they sell on an e-commerce site (me). I am trying to create an **equation** where every seller has an estimated payment release date based on the risk of future claims (given as a score), and the estimated delivery date of a product(given as a date). How can I go about doing this?

Comment: This question is so broad as to be almost meaningless. What data sources, how many observations, what time span, how many variables, how good does model preformance need to be, do you have an existing model in production?

Comment: I have 80,000 sellers , I am able to get the estimated payment release date based on delivery date, but when I want to add another variable, say , likelihood of claims, i am not sure what to do. Like should I look at distribution of model scores for every seller and then what should i do with that information?